# InfluxDB - Error deleting measurements

Tags: influxdb

i have a problem during delete some measurement entered by mistake, an example is

```
{:average=>0.08419394299266784\
{:average=>0.08420489057898521\
{:average=>0.08435888926188151\
{:average=>0.08449350467827273\
{:average=>0.08453683816041464\
```

I use `drop measurement "{:average=>0.08419394299266784\"` but i have `ERR: error parsing query: found {:average=>0.08419394299266784", expected identifier at line 1, char 17`

How can delete these mesurements?

Thanks

Comment: Can you include a bit more information. What measurement are you trying to get rid of?

Comment: the measurement names are written above

Comment: Ah sorry, I misread.

Answer (score 0):

If you issue a `SHOW MEASUREMENTS` command, you'll see that the trailing slash isn't included.

```
> show measurements
  name: measurements
  name
  ----
  {:average=>0.08419394299266784
```

To drop this measurement simply run

```
drop measurement "{:average=>0.08419394299266784 "
```